# Databricks Asset Bundle - git authentication when resources job notebook_task has source set to GIT

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks, databricks-asset-bundle

I am deploying a databricks asset bundle via Azure DevOps pipeline using `databricks bundle deploy -t <target_env>` from the `databricks-cli`. Deployment works fine no issues, however the problem when the job is run it fails to authenticate to fetch code from Azure Git. It appears there is no way to set Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory) authentication when the `notebook_task` has it's `source` set to `GIT` - I am using [Git refence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/how-to/use-repos) for the code.

I tried setting `git_provider` to **azureDevOpsServicesAad**, but only valid value for Azure DevOps is **azureDevOpsServices**.

The job is configured to run as a service principal, which has the necessary read/write permissions on the Azure Git Repo.

I understand, I can use the [Databricks REST Api to create a new git credential](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/gitcredentials/create) after obtaining an [access token for the job service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/service-prin-aad-token#--get-a-microsoft-entra-id-formerly-azure-active-directory-access-token-with-the-azure-cli), but I see no way (after looking at the yaml schema) to specify git credential id in the asset bundle yaml. There is no `git_credential_id` property for the `git_source` section?

Below is my yaml configuration for the databricks asset bundle job:

```
resources:
  jobs:
    my_job_name:
      name: my_job_name

      run_as:
        service_principal_name: ${var.run_as_user}

      permissions:
        - group_name: ${var.workspace_user_group}
          level: CAN_MANAGE_RUN
        - group_name: ${var.workspace_admin_group}
          level: CAN_MANAGE

      deployment_config:
        no_package: true

      git_source:
        git_provider: azureDevOpsServices
        git_url: https://dev.azure.com/<org-name>/<proj-name>/_git/${var.source_repo_name}
        git_branch: ${var.source_branch_name}

      max_concurrent_runs: 10
      tasks:
        - task_key: Run_All_Notebooks
          notebook_task:
            notebook_path: ${bundle.name}/_run_all_notebooks
            source: GIT
          existing_cluster_id: ${var.shared_autoscaling_cluster_id}
```

After deployment when I run the job in the Databricks UI, the error reported is:

> Task Run_All_Notebooks failed with message: Failed to checkout Git repository: PERMISSION_DENIED: Encountered an error with your Azure Active Directory credentials. Please try logging out of Azure Active Directory (https://portal.azure.com) and logging back in. This caused all downstream tasks to get skipped.

Is there any way to explicitly set AAD authentication for the `git_provider` or explicitly specify git credentials for the service principal under which the job is set to run?

Comment: Check if [this ticket](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/workflow-service-principle-owned-can-t-checkout-git-repository/m-p/3085#M262) and [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/errors-troubleshooting) are helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `WORKSPACE` as value for the `source` in a `notebook_task`.
It was possible to use `GIT`, but I didn't want to store secrets in the databricks workspace (for more details refer to **[this post here](https://community.databricks.com/t5/get-started-discussions/source-set-to-git-for-databricks-asset-bundle-notebook-task-git/m-p/64764/highlight/true#M2857)**). Below is high-level overview of my process:

- obtain access token for the service principal -
  check if existing git credential exists (I get an error saying only one git credential is allowed) and delete it if it does, then create a new git credential
- next, I use the git credential to clone a git repo into a new/existing databricks repo (check and create repo if does not exist) using a specific branch (branch name is an Azure DevOps pipeline parameter)
- I do asset `bundle deploy ...` where the `source` in the YAML is set to `WORKSPACE` pointing to the code in the updated databricks repo in previous step

I hope this is helpful to other lost souls looking for solution to the problem :)